# AppStore rejected: use of private calls refers to my own methods

Tags: ios

I received the following rejection message:

> Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:
>
> - removeItems:,
> - setSelectedSection:
> - setIsNew:
> - selectedSection
>
> The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because
>   it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

Looking through the code, I find `removeItems:` in a piece of code implemented by Xcode Core Data code generator (I have a substructure called items).

`selectedSection` and `isNew` are property in generated core data code.

The code passed last deployment. And the code passed beta review two or three weeks ago.

Does Apple forbid to use these function names in MY private code? Or is there currently an AppStore issue with false positives?

UPDATE: I received the following answer from Apple App Review team:

> Thank you for your response. For each of the selectors at issue, we
>   found the following occurrences:
>
> ... 4 method uses deleted ...
>
> To clarify, these are not necessarily direct uses of non-public APIs,
>   but as your app does not have these statically defined, they are name
>   collisions with possible private selectors, and as such revision is
>   appropriate.

The last section is especially interesting: Does this mean, that I cannot any longer choose the names of any methods free of fear that Apple might come up with the same method name? Or, to reduce it to a objc question: what is "statically defined"? `static` C-methods? class-methods?

Comment: Well, from the names of your selectors, it is not hard to imagine that the same ones would be present in table/collection vie related code ;) maybe you could try reuploading your build and explain this to Apple, the same way you did here? Sometimes it helps :) anyway, that's a really interesting case!

Comment: Of course, I wrote the same to Resolution Center, but it is always useful to see if I am falling in a common trap here or really need to dig through my code and prefix all calls with an app or company code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to proceed with the app and could not wait another day or two for another response from Apple. If anyone is interested, I pushed the message also into the developer forums, here : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63257

Comment: <Rant>You are the victim of really, really stupid programming.  I'm irate that we haven't learned by now, as a profession, that inferring real-world meaning from common strings is ridiculous.  This is how babies end up on no-fly lists!  I used to participate on a baseball discussion board.  Bill Dickey is a historically-famous player.  His name was always rendered on the board as "Bill ****ey" because some idiot thought any given string of characters always had the same context.</Rant>

Comment: @PhillipMills I would be happy to simply understand the restriction. It's not funny to implement something with reasonable naming and have a two-three days acceptance period for your names. If this is the case, I will start to put a prefix on every f-stars- method in the code. Hey, finally  C namespace by prefix is back :-( *But* I still cannot believe it, I am still hoping that either I am stupid or there is a problem in the review-code.

Comment: I don't even know how they do the check.  If they were serious about getting it right, they could use something like 'nm' to detect whether symbols were resolved in user code or in a shared library.  Or they could require a submission to include a link map.  Or...something.  I don't know the right answer, right now, but there has to be a better way than comparing strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for rejection is actually really that I am using selectors that Apple decided to make introduce as private selectors.

This can happen at any time, with any version and there is no testing facility but the app review (at the time of this writing).

It seems that Apple changed policy here, earlier, they just send out a warning, nowadays the app is refused.

The solution is actually simple, but can require major efforts.

- rename the selectors listed in the review report
- rename properties, also dynamic properties from core-data, that match the report. In my case, all reported fields were core-data properties. This required renaming of database fields and thus I had to add a new DB schema version and rename the fields accordingly and initialize the db stack with auto-migration enabled.