# Can you rename the coredata accessors without renaming the entire entity?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am trying to get upload an archive of my app to App Store Connect and keep running into the issue of `The app references non-public selectors core data site:developer.apple.com`.

I have narrowed down the issue to the CoreData generated accessors for two of my entities, `Folder` and `Item`. The issue is that the accessor to add one of these items to a one-to-many relationship seems to collide with a non-public Objective-C function. Here is a link to a post about a similar issue.

[AppStore rejected: use of private calls refers to my own methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504260/appstore-rejected-use-of-private-calls-refers-to-my-own-methods)

For instance the addItemsObject is one of the non-public selectors that was added.

```
extension Folder {
  
  @objc(addItemsObject:)
  @NSManaged public func addToItems(_ value: Item)
  
  @objc(removeItemsObject:)
  @NSManaged public func removeFromItems(_ value: Item)
  
  @objc(addItems:)
  @NSManaged public func addToItems(_ values: NSSet)
  
  @objc(removeItems:)
  @NSManaged public func removeFromItems(_ values: NSSet)
  
}
```

Renaming the @objc(addItemsObject:) to @objc(addItemsObject_1:) fixes the issue and allows the archive to validate and upload but it breaks the app with the error `Unrecognized selector addItemsObject_1`.

Is there anyway to rename just this accessor without having to rename my entities?

Comment: When does the "unrecognized selector" message occur? What is your code doing at the time?

Comment: The Objective-C selectors are generated from the relationship name `items`.

Comment: There is no reason why you would need to rename that relationship, maybe all you need to do is clean the build folder and possibly delete the content in DerivedData.

Comment: @TomHarrington That "unrecognized selector" message occurs when I am trying to add an item to the one-to-many relationship after renaming the accessors. However renaming them the app validates correctly. Which led me to deduce that renaming the accessors is the solution but how how to go about it is a problem that likely requires a lot more Objective-C.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think you are correct that I should not have to rename. I have not been able to get the warning to disappear by cleaning the build folder or deleting derived data. The app was uploaded to App Store Connect so it may just remain a warning for the time being.